# How can I get more critical hits in my combos and maximize my combo meter?

Tags: achievements, batman-arkham-origins

At rank 12 of the Shadow Vigilante challenge, you have to get 20 critical hits in a single combo.  In the previous games, getting criticals were relatively easy.  Just attack immediately after you hit an enemy... But in this game, it seems criticals just don't seem to register when I think they should making getting this challenge more difficult than it really is.  I'm also playing on hard so they tend to take swings at me very frequently so it's hard to get into a groove with the hits without getting hit back.

**Any tips on how to get more critical hits in my combos in a fight so I can get to the next rank?**

Comment: The thing is, in all Arkham games, critical strikes have to be unlocked first. In AA and AC you could unlock those relatively early in the game, but in AO you'll have to progress very far into the game until you can unlock critical strikes. As if to offset that, you get critical counters early on, but pulling off 20 critical counters in a single combo is really tough. If memory serves well, critical strikes are unlocked after you finish the Sheva Most Wanted mission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tried-and-true strategy that will help you rack up high combos full of criticals and not get hit.

First of all, you need to find a large group of thugs to fight.  You can't get high combos if there aren't enough thugs and you knock them all out too soon.  You'll need to be able to deal 23 attacks at a minimum, 3 regular hits since criticals don't seem to count until you reach special combo status (the next hit after the initial 3 can start counting criticals) followed by the 20 criticals.  The more there is, the easier this will be.  Try to find a crime in progress, at least these encounters, there generally are less guns you have to deal with.

The secret to this challenge... dodging.

That's right, build up your combo to reach special combo status, then dodge and hit, dodge and hit and repeat that pattern until you get the required amount of hits.  Dodging pretty much guarantees you won't get hit so you're safe from attacks.  And when you attack after landing, the game counts it as a critical.  If you build up enough charge on your shock gloves, criticals will increase your combo multiplier by 3 building up your multiplier even faster.

Just note that while this strategy helps build up your combo, it alone doesn't help much in the challenge maps, you can't build up a lot of points doing this.  You need to mix in different gadgets for variety and takedowns to take advantage of that multiplier.